# raggedleft (right-aligned) entries in pmatrix?

Tags: amsmath

I'm using `pmatrix` from `amsmath` package and would like the output to align all entries in the same column to be align on the right hand side, as shown here in the code:

```
\[ \begin{pmatrix}
  -1 &  1 & -2\\
   0 & -1 &  4\\
   0 &  0 &  1
\end{pmatrix} \]
```

by default, `pmatrix` will center.

Any way to do this?

Comment: from the `amsmath` users guide: "(If you need left or right alignment in a column or other special formats you must resort to array.)" (p.8)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `pmatrix*` environment of the [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath and some very useful complements
\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        -1 & 1 & -2\\
        0 & -1 & 4\\
        0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The new `tabstackengine` package can also do this, including different column alignments, as in the 2nd example.  EDITED to reflect updated package (bug workaround no longer needed).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[ \setstacktabbedgap{1ex}\parenMatrixstack[r]{%
  -1 &  1 & {-}2\\
   0 & -1 &  4\\
   0 &  0 &  1
} \]
\[ \left(\tabularCenterstack{lcr}{%
  -1 &  1 & {-}2\\
   0 & -1 &  4\\
   0 &  0 &  1
}\right) \]
\end{document}
```

[image]